# how expensive are RuntimeWarning warnings on performance for computation on big data

Tags: python, pandas, warnings, runtimeexception

I have many situations where computations encounter things like:

```
-divide by zero
-np.nan values in a column that I compute df['col'].quantile(0.5)
-np.nan values in groupby objects that are then used like grouped.agg('sum')
```

etc

I don't get any errors but do get `RuntimeWarning` messages. Now since my data is very large I'm wondering whether these warnings result in performance degradation and if so is there anyway I can bypass them.

example:

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py:87: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  rtruediv=arith_method(lambda x, y: operator.truediv(y, x),

lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py:720: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal

lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:3403: RuntimeWarning: Invalid value encountered in median
  RuntimeWarning)

lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:3386: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  x2 = take(ap, indices_above, axis=axis) * weights_above
```

Comment: Are you wondering whether the *warning mechanism* is expensive, or are you wondering about *the thing the warning is warning you about*?

Comment: the warning mechanism. I know why I'm getting the warning i.e. divide by 0,  data element = inf or np.nan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A warning amounts to several simple operations, including hashing to determine if a warning has already been issued and whether that warning should be issued more than once, and where the warning occurred. These are fast, but they aren't free.

All those operations occur regardless of whether a warning is actually printed, and this is independent of the cost of the heuristic used to determine whether the library issuing the warning *should* warn you that something isn't quite right.

Here's a breakdown of the price of just calling `warning.warn`

```
In [4]: %timeit [warnings.warn("Hey You") for i in range(1000)]
ipython-script.py:257: UserWarning: Hey You # Notice this only was printed once
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.2 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit [i + i for i in range(1000)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 53.4 µs per loop
```

So 1 millisecond for 1000 warning operations. Scale that up to the number of warning generating operations you perform * number of times those operations occur, and you'll have some idea of how much time it costs you.

Will these warnings cost you a couple of compute-minutes on a compute-day long job? Yes. But will have the answer in a day and five minutes be worse than having the answer in a day? Probably not.

Comment: Thank you for the illustration. I appreciate it. So, there isn't anyway to turn OFF warnings even internally?

Comment: @codingknob: While you can install a warnings filter to disable warnings, it won't really be cheaper than the default.

Comment: Correct. Even if you disable the warning machinery, because that machinery is designed to be as fine-grained as possible, it can't know it shouldn't generate a warning until after it has figured out the type of warning, where that warning was from (in source code), and whether it has issued that warning already.